# How to create a new command for references

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I have tried to create a new command for making references better so I can get `Eq.(*numer*)` each time I call it, instead of just the number.
So I made

```
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\reff}{Eq.(\ref)}
```

But when using it, I get just `Eq()` and the name of the label I am calling instead of using the original command. 
Is there anyway to create something like this or is there any other command to make somtehing like that?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You need to pass an argument, so `\newcommand{\reff}[1]{Eq.~(\ref{#1})}`.  But instead doing this from scratch, you should look at the `cleveref` package, which provides `\cref`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, packages like `cleveref` exists.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
test

\begin{equation}
a \label{myeq}
\end{equation}


test \cref{myeq} test

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But in case you want to know what went wrong with your custom command: the argument was missing

```
 \newcommand{\reff}[1]{Eq.(\ref{#1})}
```